# What format Liquibase Rollback rollbackDate uses?

Tags: liquibase

I am using liquibase to have changes in oracle database 
and running following commands

```
clean -PLocalLiquibaseScriptExecution liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackDate="2016-12-09T11:49:00"

clean -PLocalLiquibaseScriptExecution liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackDate='2016-12-09T11:49:00'

clean -PLocalLiquibaseScriptExecution liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackDate=2016-12-09T11:49:00  


clean -PLocalLiquibaseScriptExecution liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackDate="DEC 09 2016"
```

> For all tries facing [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.0.5:rollback (default-cli) on
>   project liquibase: Error setting up or running Liquibase: Error
>   parsing rollbackDate: Unparseable date: "2016-12-09T11:49:00" [ERROR]
>   Date must match pattern: MMM d, yyyy [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

For

```
clean -PLocalLiquibaseScriptExecution liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackDate="DEC 09, 2016"  

INFO 12/9/16 1:15 PM:liquibase: null: null: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 12/9/16 1:15 PM:liquibase: null: null: Reading from DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 12/9/16 1:15 PM:liquibase: null: null: Successfully released change log lock
```

But  how to provide times like hh:mm:ss also  ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in new versions ISO Date Format is also supported: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/2131161c60549f0eb48c20cdbf4ed01f9cfd3997